# Как разрешить проблему импорта в проекте FastAPI (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-import

У меня существует проект на FastAPI который реализует простую логику авторизации и регистрации пользователя(Для этого я использую библиотеку FastAPI-users). Все отлично. Но есть проблема с импортами. Вот моя файловая структура:

[image: Файловая структура проекта FastAPI]

Так же вот файлы main.py и database.py (Сейчас они будут нужны)
[image: Код файла main.py]

[image: Код файла database.py]

При попытке запуска проекта. `uvicorn main:app --reload` Я получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка импорта в терминале с кодом NoModulFound]

Я понимаю что у меня проблема в импорте. Но не могу понять в чем проблема. Он жалуется на строчки `from auth.database import User` и `from config import DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_USER` но я совсем не понимаю, где тут ошибка. Я понимаю что скорее всего это элементарное решение, но не могли бы вы его подсказать. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо за ваше время!

Comment: [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)